# ubuntu is slow after xrandr with 2x2 scale

Tags: 14.04, performance, xrandr

I recently bought a Dell XPS which comes with HighDpi resolution (3200x1800).

For some reason, when I extend my laptop screen to another monitor (1920x1800) all things on this second monitor get really big. So, I could fix this running the following `xrandr` command:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --output DP1 --auto --panning 3840x2160+3200+0 --scale 2x2 --right-of eDP1
```

`eDP1` - main monitor

`DP1` - extended monitor

Everything was beautiful, but the computer start perform really slow for any task (even running only sublime for text editing). CPU and memory are ok. The reason seems to be the screen rendering...

Could someone give me a reasonable explanation of why it is happening?

Thank you!

`$ xrandr --current`

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 7040 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 3200x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   3200x1800      60.0*+   48.0  
   2048x1536      60.0  
   1920x1440      60.0  
   1856x1392      60.0  
   1792x1344      60.0  
   1920x1200      60.0  
   1920x1080      59.9  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 connected 3840x2160+3200+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm panning 3840x2160+3200+0
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

**UPDATE:**

I couldn't fix this. So I've just matched the resolutions to avoid the resolution difference:

```
$xrandr --current
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1936 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   3200x1800      60.0 +   48.0  
   2048x1536      60.0  
   1920x1440      60.0  
   1856x1392      60.0  
   1792x1344      60.0  
   1920x1200      60.0  
   1920x1080      59.9* 
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 connected 1920x1080+16+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Hmm. I had a similar (sort of) issue with my Raspberry Pi display when I rotated it in the config file. Graphics performance was really poor. Turned out it was redrawing in software rather than on the actual hardware. Later. the Pi foundation released a fix.

Comment: Thanks @AndroidDev. didn't manage to fix this. So I've matched the resolutions of both screens to avoid scale difference. Thanks anyway.